# Sharing dependencies between plugins

Tags: maven

I have a Maven project with two plugins that require the same dependency (which should *not* be packaged with the application):

```xml
<!-- pom.xml excerpt -->
<plugins>
    <plugin>
        <groupId>...</groupId>
        <artifactId>...</artifactId>
        <version>...</version>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.example</groupId>
                <artifactId>foo</artifactId>
                <version>1</version>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </plugin>

    <plugin>
        <groupId>...</groupId>
        <artifactId>...</artifactId>
        <version>...</version>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.example</groupId>
                <artifactId>foo</artifactId>
                <version>1</version>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </plugin>
</plugins>
```

Is there a way to specify the dependency *once* such that it's available to both (or possibly all) plugins?

So far the only options I could come up with are using a property to specify the version (thus keeping the version numbers consistent), or declaring the dependency as a project dependency with a `test` scope (which I don't think it's a clean solution).

Comment: If you want to handle the version number, I would go for the property. I don't know any mechanism to declare "global" plugin dependencies, nor do I think that this is especially useful since the number of plugins that you declare dependencies for is usually below 5.

Comment: Why do you need to define supplemental dependencies for plugins? Usually all plugins define their dependencies already ? Can you elaborate more in detail what the problem is?

Comment: @JFMeier Yes I figured I was dealing with a very specific edge case (that would explain the lack of information I found while I was researching this issue), I guess I'll define a property then. Thank you.

Comment: @khmarbaise Right, the reason I need that dependency in both plugins (Jetty and Liquibase) it's because I'm working with an Oracle DB, and since both plugins require DB access I need to import the JDBC driver.

Comment: Ok now it's clear to me why you need that. Best would be use a property but there is no mechanism to globally configuration dependencies for plugins in an other way...

Comment: @khmarbaise Indeed, declaring a property seems like the only way to go around this. Thank you.